# Multithreading executor service-java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have executorservice executing a particular thread. Executing the thread, it goes to sleep after sometime. But at this time, i want another thread to be started executing the same and it goes on like this. I tried the following program using executor service but it behaves like a sequential processing. Please suggest me what changes or any other classes in java to achieve the above scenario.

```
class WorkerThread implements Runnable {

    private String command;

    public WorkerThread(String s){
        this.command=s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Start. Command = "+command);
        processCommand();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" End.");
    }

    private void processCommand() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.command;
    }
}


  class ThreadPool {
      public static int times=0;
 public static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

       int i=0;
        while(i<2)
        {
        Runnable worker = new WorkerThread("proud");
         executor.execute(worker);
         times++;
         //executor.shutdown();
       i++;
        }
       executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        }
        System.out.println("Finished all threads");
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "it behaves like a parallel processing?"  What output do you expect from the program?  What do you get instead?

Comment: sorry i changed. its sequential

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  Since the thread pool only has one thread, it can only run one thread at a time.  Now there will be multiple threads active, but only will actually be running.  If you want one to start when the previous one else, use `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`

Comment: The big question still is "why?".

Comment: Probably sequential because you created a thread "pool" that only has one thread.

Comment: @kayaman because instead of timer being started every time i like to sleep the thread every time it enters the run(). I want to find alternative for timer and parallel processing. Is ScheduleThreadPoolExecutor a good substitute?

Comment: If you literally want to execute a thread at regular intervals, I'd think SheduledThreadPool would be a good choice.  Take a look at `crontab` first though.

Comment: Added, timer only supports sequential processes